# Insert HTML on Flutter Web and CROS problems with IFrame

Tags: flutter

I want to embed a stripe pricing table on my flutter website.

I have done:

```dart
 _registerElement() {
    final src = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8,"+ Uri.encodeComponent("""<script async src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/pricing-table.js"></script>
<stripe-pricing-table pricing-table-id="prctbl_1NsNibDmGGo1DisCQQrsW4ta"
publishable-key="pk_live_51NUn9HDmGGo1DisCdvpjUTEgLYqNbBqLOQr7NtR0mNMnU79apIQcz9ACjJJ8Hlj2paxIK164LZanFAmK0Vp5V7XZ00k7FC2YnT">
</stripe-pricing-table>""");
    // ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
        'stripe-pricing',
            (int viewId) => _iframeElement
          ..width = '100%'
          ..height = '100%'
        ..style.border = '0'
        ..allowFullscreen = true
        ..src=src
    );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        HtmlElementView(
              key: ValueKey('stripe-pricing'),
              viewType: 'stripe-pricing'),
        ),
...
```

However, I get this error `DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': Invalid target origin 'null' in a call to 'postMessage'.`

The problem comes from the cross-origin of  elements that is mentioned on the HtmlElementView [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/HtmlElementView-class.html).

Is there an easy way to embed an HTML element without using iframe?